# rails, how to pass hidden field in link_to for a delete request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hidden-field, link-to

i was wondering how someone can pass hidden fields in a link_to performing a delete request. i have..

```
<%= link_to "delete", feed_item,     method: :delete,
                                     confirm: "You sure?",
                                     title: feed_item.content,
                                     user_id: user_id %>
<% end %>
```

ive been trying to pass user_id into my controller's destroy action but it cant seem to find params[:user_id]

it seems like its possible to pass hidden values when the method is a :post, but how can i do so in a :delete?

i essentially just want the user_id in my destroy action, so it can redirect back to the users profile page.

thank you

Comment: HTTP DELETE requests don't fully support having a body, unlike POSTs, which is where extra data would be located. You could potentially try and include the data in the headers, but this seems overly complicated and should probably never be attempted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way would be to either put feed_item under user resource or user current_user method in the controller

if you decide to put it under user resource the modify your routes file as

```
resources :users do
  resources feed_items, :only=>[:destroy]
end
```

and than in your link to delete change the path to 
    user_feed_item_path

Alternatively if you have current_user method from using any sort of authentication solution you can just use that in your redirect path

Comment: oh i wasn't using a direct object, but seeing your line of code gave me an idea of how to solve it! thanks! i just did

redirect_to user_path(@pub_message.to_id)

@pub_message was already available, so i got the id from that instead. thanks!